# Difference between IBM Websphere Application Server and IBM Websphere Process Server?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, wid

Im currently looking into the difference between IBM Websphere Application Server and IBM Websphere Process Server?

I am aware that the Process Server is like a higher level layer ontop of the App server, but was wondering if development using either would be the same or similar. I have been working with integration developer and App server for a while now, and was wondering if the skills transfered across for Process server.

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process server has a built in WAS.

You can build and deploy standard Java EE applications on both servers this part carries over.

The process server is an extended ESB. If you want to create mediations and process flows, etc, with the full WID feature set then you require the process server. These can be created with the WebSphere Integration Developer as well. However I doubt that you where using these as they won't run on a simple WAS.

Creating mediations and process flows is totally different from the standard Java EE programming.

Answer (score 6):

Udo's answer is correct but i would like to add a few more things to this.

WPS is superceded with the release of IBM BPM V7.5 which was released in June this year. IBM BPM is a merger of two BPM products - WPS and WebSphere Lombardi edition.

Do note that both WPS and BPM 7.5 will use typically a older version of WAS (currently they use a WAS 7.x  version) while WAS 8 has been in the marketplace for a longer period of time.

To do Java EE stuff, you are better off using WAS as they will keep up pace with the Java EE specs while WPS and BPM 7.5 lags and you will not be able to take advantage as they lag for a good period of time.

WAS's focuses on Java EE and providing the base for products like WPS, WESB, WebSphere Portal etc. WPS and BPM 7.5 focus on providing a BPM platform for users to build and deploy their BPM solutions.

Hope this gives some clarity

Comment: ++ to Manglu's answer. From a licensing perspective it is heaps cheaper to deploy regular business apps to WAS. And it is cheaper to deploy mediations to WESB. Leave WPS and its successor BPM to run your business processes (ie, the BPEL).